# preg_match - What is the pattern of that?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a php class for URL rewriting. I want to route this urls:

```
 - services-paris/
 - services-paris/8/
 - services/
```

The formula is: `services[ "-" + (city) ]? / [ (0-9) + "/" ]?`

First thing is `[ "-" + (city) ]?`, means: is optional + must start with "-", but to return only the city.

Second thing is `[ (0-9) + "/" ]?`, means: is optional + only numbers + end with "/" but return only numbers.

The second thing is pagination.

Finally I need these informations to know the city and the page.

So.. what is the pattern, I an newbie at regex.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this regex :

```
services(?:-([^\/]+))?\/(?:(\d+)\/)?$
```

It's gonna give you a table of matches which contains :

1. The city name (wihtout the '-')
2. The number after the first '/' and before the second '/'

Note that your city name mustn't contain any '/' character.

[Example](https://regex101.com/r/uF8aS8/1)

Comment: it's ok but there are some problems. if the number (page) parameter isn't numeric, and it's alpha.. it will return only the first parameter (the city, if isset). If isset page and page isn't numeric, i don't want to match. Exemple: request: services-paris/asd/ => will return city: paris. FALSE, i don't want to match.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex for `preg_match`:

```
'~\bservices(?:-([a-zA-Z. ]+))?(?:/(\d+))?/~'
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zV8wL3/1)

**RegEx Breakup:**

```
\b                  # word boundary
services            # literal text services
(?:-([a-zA-Z. ]+))? # optional group containing - and a city name
(?:/(\d+))?         # optional group containing / and a page number
/                   # trailing slash
```

**PS:** city name and page number will be available in captured group #1 and #2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple regex with a breakdown

```
(\w+)    # Capture 1 or more letters for 'services'
(?:-     # Begin non capturing group with '-'
(\w+)    # Capture 1 or more letters for city
)?       # End non capturing group (optionally matched)
(?:\/    # Begin non capturing group with '/'
(\d+)    # Capture 1 or more numbers for pagination
)?       # End non capturing group (optionally matched)
```

You can see it in action [here](http://regexr.com/3b4ni)

Comment: `\w+` is not enough to match a city name. ie. `San Francisco`.

Comment: `([^\/]+)` Here's what I would use. Matches everything but the '/' character.

Comment: Spaces would be URL-escaped, surely, which would be all kinds of untidy. Anyway, I'd expect cities to be normalised to one word - e.g. sanfrancisco.